# How to set up and maintain directory structure in TFS build server?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, msbuild, build-server

So I have this pretty huge solution with many projects, few of them use dlls from other projects in this solution, some projects copy files to other directories after build is performed. (as post build events)

when I build the solution locally on my machine, everything is great and working, but when i configure a build, and build it on build server (we use TFS) something goes wrong and i get a  an error when i try to load one of the applications in this solution. (the error does not give me much data on what went wrong)

so before i sit to debug all of this. does anybody know how can i smartly manage all the build actions that are performed locally and via build server and see the deltas?

I would like to be able to build the solution exactly the same on build server as i do on my machine (with directory structure, post build events..etc)

thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

The generally accepted way to do what you're after is to use NuGet for managing your assembly references. You can publish your dependent assemblies into NuGet as part of a continuous delivery process, then reference (and update!) those dependencies in the solutions that consume them as necessary.

This removes ambiguity ("What version of Foo.dll is Project X using?") and reduces runtime errors ("Why is Project X using Foo.dll 3.0? It was never tested with 3.0! It needs to run with 2.7!").